# Load different .env file with a Symfony 4 command

Tags: symfony, environment-variables, command-line-interface, symfony4

`.env` file is parsed when running a Symfony 4 command (if dotenv is available).

This is working fine when developping, but also, I want to test my code (so another environment), hence I need to load another `.env` file.

I love what Docker did to run a container:

```
docker run -e MYVAR1 --env MYVAR2=foo --env-file ./env.list ubuntu bash
```

So I am looking to achieve same thing with Symfony:

```
php bin/console --env-file ./.env.test
```

right now, I am doing this:

```
export $(grep -v '^#' .env.test | xargs) && php bin/console
```

Comment: I think the idea is that outside of development you are supposed to define your env variables elsewhere.  If you look at the bin/console code you will see that it loads .env based on the existence of an external APP_ENV variable.  Of course an easy work around is to just make a console_test.

Comment: This is definitely something that should, IMO at least, be supported. Being able to run a command that, for example, executes tests and requires a different database requires a change in environment variable and being able to change that + n other vars by specifying a different file makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

I opted for editing the `bin/console` file directly to facilitate the different `.env` file, which isn't an issue since it's a file the developer has control over. I updated the relevant section to;

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['APP_ENV'])) {
    if (!class_exists(Dotenv::class)) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('APP_ENV environment variable is not defined. You need to define environment variables for configuration or add "symfony/dotenv" as a Composer dependency to load variables from a .env file.');
    }
}

$input = new ArgvInput();
$env = $input->getParameterOption(['--env', '-e'], $_SERVER['APP_ENV'] ?? 'dev', true);

switch ($env) {
    case 'test':
        (new Dotenv())->load(__DIR__.'/../.env.test');
        break;

    case 'dev':
    default:
        (new Dotenv())->load(__DIR__.'/../.env');
        break;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did finally. I submit a PR => https://github.com/symfony/recipes/pull/385

Comment: Ahh I didn't see that, nice @ThomasDecaux :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your app/bootstrap.php and bin/console binary is well updated.
In my case I just updated bin/console by adding :

```
require dirname(__DIR__).'/app/bootstrap.php';
```